# How do I list my profile in the profile list after downloading the Drupal distribution with drush make?

Tags: users, distributions

I am creating a profile for my site.

So I basically have the following files:

```
myproject.info
myproject.make
myproject.profile
```

Evertime I run

```
drush make myproject.make
```

the drupal files + modules are copied but during install I only see the profiles: standard and minimal.

**How to make my profile myproject visible in the list?**

UPDATE:

I copied my profile inside the profile folder of a Drupal installation.
Now my profile is being listed. But I prefer this should be done from a script.

I asume I should edit the make file to copy the new profile inside the profile folder. I am not sure this can be done from within the make file therefore I assume should run a .sh file instead.

I am waiting for some suggestions.

Comment: Where is myproject.module?

Comment: @Triskelion the .module file is not used when creating installation profiles but the myproject.profile is used instead: see http://drupal.org/node/1022020

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom sh file that does the drush make, and moves the profile files for you.